# How can I make it possible to edit (format) the text in "GridControl" using "RichTextEdit1"?

Tags: c#, datagridview, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui, devexpress-gridcontrol

Windows 7 x64
Visual Studio 2015 x64
DevExpress 17.1.5
MSSql Server 2014

```
CREATE TABLE "tbl0410Categories" (
    "CategoryId" INT NOT NULL,
    "Name" NVARCHAR(max) NOT NULL,
    "fotoLink" VARCHAR(1000) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "text1" VARCHAR(7000) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ("CategoryId")
)
```

"GridControl" is connected to the MSSql Server table
[screen 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4DVr.jpg)

Tried to do as shown in the screenshot.
But how to format the text is unclear.
Probably need to additionally place the formatting panel on the "WinForm".
But how to make it possible to format the text in GridControl using the format bar?
[screen 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7Oma.jpg)
[screen the formatting panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axGvN.jpg)

**Question**
How can I make it possible to edit (format) the text in "GridControl" using "RichTextEdit1"?

I want to see a solution for the two options.
It depends on what it will be easier to do.
*Option 1*
"RichTextEdit1" is located in the "GridControl" (see screen)
[screen 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDU5n.jpg)

or
*Option 2*
"RichTextEdit1" is in the "WinForms"
(see screen)
[screen 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xJoL.jpg)

Project - [link](http://dropmefiles.com/90R3E)
[the picture shows how to download](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FW9eu.jpg)

Comment: What do you mean with "But it does not work"? Is there no text or it can't be edited?

Comment: @MarkoJuvančič   Has supplemented a question.
*PS. Please, let me know if my question is still unclear to you.
I count on your help.
Thank you.*